# update image in android custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I need to update the third image in my custom adapter, I've tried using the getView method with no luck

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) rowView.getParent();
ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
myCustomAdapter.getView(2, image, rl);              
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the notifyDataSetChanged whill redraw the hole list items, and call getView for your adapter. I think that the update must be forwarded to the getView from your adapter.

Comment: So what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` is an `abstract` class (i.e. has no implementation in `Adapter` class and you need to implement it to change the `View` returned from the Adapter to fill the `View`). You should implement it in your custom adapter and check that value of position to change the image.

Basically, what happens is each time your `Adapter` takes an item from the data, passes it to `getView` to fill the `View` that will be used in this row with this data.

Answer (score 0):

```
//ListView list
View view = list.getChildAt(position);

((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

R.id.list_image is the id for your image in custom list row defined in xml.

This is a temporary solution though, because when list is scrolled, this item will later be redrawn by your custom adapter. For that you need to alter the array that was supplied to Custom Adapter to set items. For that you might need Uri instead.